# How to shift HERE Map View to the right when navigating

Tags: android, view, navigation, maps, here-api

I am making a navigation application using HERE SDK Android. During the middle of navigation, I want to expand an overlayed view on top of my map on the left. This causes some of my navigation views to be cut off. So I want to shift the center of my navigation to the right. That way the route and my arrows will be shifted to the right of the screen where they can be seen.

Is there a way to accomplish this using the HERE android SDK?

I have tried looking at MapSchemes but this does not seem to do what I want.

I think to put it more succinctly I want to shift my center point of the map to the right during navigation.

Comment: Don't do it manually. Just set navigation manager to auto center. There is one option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `setTransformCenter` in the `Map` class.
That sounds like what you are looking for:

> Sets a center coordinate for Map transformations such as zooming.
>   Transformations performed after calling this method will be based on
>   this new center coordinate. The transform center may be different than
>   the Map center. Developer must not use this method and setPadding(int,
>   int, int, int) at the same time as the only one of them will be taken
>   into account, depending on the order of invocation.

See https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-starter/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/mapping/Map.html#setTransformCenter-android.graphics.PointF-