# Here maps offset position indicator center

Tags: ios, here-api

I'm using the Here iOS SDK. I set position indicator via:

```
let mapMarker = NMAMapMarker(geoCoordinates: NMAGeoCoordinates(), icon: nmaImage)
mapView.positionIndicator.set(displayObject: mapMarker, toLayer: NMAMapLayerType.foreground)
```

That works, but position indicator apears at the center of the screen. I need to set some offset (or padding) in order to display position indicator way below the center (some offset or padding), so driver could see more of the road ahead.

Comment: There is an anchorOffset parameter, have you checked that? 
https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMAMapMarker.html#%2Fc:objc(cs)NMAMapMarker(py)anchorOffset

Comment: @Tomas Doesn't work for me, because that will offset image of position indicator, real location is still in the center of the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the map view's transform center: https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMAMapView.html#%2Fc:objc(cs)NMAMapView(py)transformCenter

Check also related SO posts
[Here API offset map center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43325005/here-api-offset-map-center) and (for Android in that case) [How to shift HERE Map View to the right when navigating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55643228/how-to-shift-here-map-view-to-the-right-when-navigating)

Comment: Thanks. I found that kind of solution in the meantime. `mapView.transformCenter = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.9)`